# Openfire silent isntallation and configuration

Tags: openfire

Are there any options to silent install openfire ?

I was trying to automate openfire configuration . When seen , the only file that changes after configuration is C:\Program Files(x86)\Openfire\conf\openfile.xml.

```
<jive> 
  <adminConsole> 
    <!-- Disable either port by setting the value to -1 -->  
    <port>9090</port>  
    <securePort>9091</securePort> 
    </adminConsole>  
   <locale>en</locale>  
   <!-- Network settings. By default, Openfire will bind to all network interfaces.
  Alternatively, you can specify a specific network interfaces that the server
  will listen on. For example, 127.0.0.1. This setting is generally only useful
   on multi-homed servers. -->  
 <!--
  <network>
    <interface></interface>
 </network>
 -->  
  <connectionProvider> 
  <className>org.jivesoftware.database.DefaultConnectionProvider</className> 
  </connectionProvider>  
    <database> 
      <defaultProvider> 
      <driver>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driver>  
      <serverURL>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/schema_openfire;appName=jive</serverURL>  
      <username>sa</username>  
      <password>yadayada</password>  
      <testSQL>select 1</testSQL>  
      <testBeforeUse>false</testBeforeUse>  
      <testAfterUse>false</testAfterUse>  
      <minConnections>5</minConnections>  
      <maxConnections>25</maxConnections>  
      <connectionTimeout>1.0</connectionTimeout> 
  </defaultProvider> 
 </database>  
 <setup>true</setup> 
 </jive>
```

the domain name after copying configured openfire.xml , never updates the needed domain name. It remains Localhost IP 127.0.0.1 no matter what .

Has any done any openfire installation and configuration automation ??

Comment: This is exactly the question I have, too. I've not been able to figure out where Openfire stores the server name, the only way I can change it is manually via the admin interface. Have you been able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The majority of OpenFire's configuration is stored in the database and not in the configuration file.  These values are visible on the "Server Properties" tab in the OpenFire admin console.

To accomplish an automated installation you'd need to have your script that inserts / updates the ofProperty table to set the "xmpp.domain" key to the appropriate value.

I would recommend having your automated install create all of the OpenFire database tables and modify that script to specify the domain name instead of relying on OpenFire to automatically create the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Openfire has now ability for autoconfiguration.
Create

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\Openfire\conf\openfire.xml
```

with next entry, modify accordingly, then restart service.

```xml
    <autosetup>
        <run>true</run>
        <locale>en</locale>
        <xmpp>
            <domain>localhost</domain>
            <fqdn>localhost</fqdn>
            <auth>
                <anonymous>true</anonymous>
            </auth>
            <socket>
                <ssl>
                    <active>true</active>
                </ssl>
            </socket>
        </xmpp>
        <encryption>
            <algorithm>AES</algorithm>
            <key>some-key</key>
        </encryption>
        <database>
            <mode>standard</mode>
            <defaultProvider>
                <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                <serverURL>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/a-database</serverURL>
                <username>a-database</username>
                <password>a-password</password>
                <minConnections>5</minConnections>
                <maxConnections>25</maxConnections>
                <connectionTimeout>1.0</connectionTimeout>
            </defaultProvider>
        </database>
        <admin>
            <email>admin@example.com</email>
        <password>admin</password>
        </admin>
        <authprovider>
            <mode>default</mode>
        </authprovider>
        <users>
            <user1> <!-- Use incremental numbers for more users, eg: user2, user3 -->
                <username>jane</username> <!-- Required -->
                <password>secret</password> <!-- Required -->
                <name>Jane Doe</name>
                <email>user1@example.org</email>
                <roster>
                    <item1> <!-- Use incremental numbers for more items, eg: item2, item3 -->
                        <jid>john@example.com</jid>
                        <nickname>John</nickname>
                    </item1>
                </roster>
            </user1>
        </users>
    </autosetup>
```

Source:

[Openfire - Autosetup](https://download.igniterealtime.org/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/install-guide.html#autosetup)